# Error insertando en la BD mediante EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, entity-framework

Tengo este modelo generado por EF

```
 public partial class Ventas
{
    public Ventas()
    {
        this.Caja = new HashSet<Caja>();
        this.VentasLinias = new HashSet<VentasLinias>();
    }

    public string weblogin { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
```

}

Pero uso este otro mediante automapper para hacer las operaciones de inserción en la BD.

```
public class VentasModel
{
    public string weblogin { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Caja> caja { get; set; }
    public List<VentasLinias> linias { get; set; }
}
```

Al intentar guardar en la BD me da este error el código que uso es este

```
 try
        {
            var destino = mapper.Map<VentasModel, Ventas>(venta);
            db.Ventas.Add(destino);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
```

El error que recibo es este

> Solo se admiten claves generadas por el almacenamiento para las columnas de identidad. La columna de clave 'weblogin' tiene el tipo 'SqlServer.varchar', que no es un tipo válido para una columna de identidad.

En la base de datos tengo esta tabla donde considero una clave compuesta por estos tres campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias,

Comment: Intenta removiendo el primary key en weblogin, puede que ahí no te lo tome sql.

Comment: gracias , pero por mi diseño de base de datos necesito que sean estos tres campos ya que weblogin = central , id = 1 , tiendaventa = 1 es diferente de weblogin  = central , id=1 , tiendaventa =2

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una nueva columna `CajaId` a tu tabla `Caja`, 
luego actualiza tu clase para hacer notar que tu *primary key* será `CajaId`.

`weblogin` ,`id`, `tiendaventa` puede ser usada como clave natural de tu aplicación.